# Using gvfs or other automounter on ubuntu server?

Tags: server, automation, automount

I have a headless machine running Ubuntu Server sitting in my closet. I would like to have USB disks automounted when I plug them in just like on my laptop. Is it possible to set up gvfs or some other automounting system for use in a console and ssh environment, with no X11 installed?

Answer (score 2):

There is a daemon application ivman:

```
sudo apt-get install ivman
```

Or according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) :

```
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would mount things under the same names as GNOME or KDE does.

Comment: Also, I thought ivman has been unmaintained for years.